# Funcion returning an extra 0

Tags: c++11, stdvector

I have this function which calculates distance between two point, everything works fine but I get an extra zero at the end.

My input:

```
2  3, 12 30, 40 50, 5  1, 12 10, 3  4
```

```
float bruteForce(vector< pair <float,float> >::const_iterator brute, vector< pair <float,float> >::const_iterator end, float m)
{
    float min = FLT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)  
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < m; j++)  
        {
            if ( dist(brute[i].first, brute[i].second, brute[j].first, brute[j].second ) < min)  
            {
                min = dist(brute[i].first, brute[i].second, brute[j].first, brute[j].second); 
                cout << min << endl; 
            }
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

output:

```
1.41421, 
11.4018, 
34.4093, 
0
```

Comment: Time to step through your code, statement by statement, in a debugger. And to verify the input to make sure it's valid and doesn't contain any values that it shouldn't.

Comment: Why are you using `float` as a loop index? This is almost guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: Yeah thats stupid, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

A 0 indicates "no distance", so there must be two points on the same location.
When I look at your input, it appears the 3 is there  twice.
So this is the shortest distance, after that, it's impossible to find anything else shorter.

Comment: These are coordinate pairs, the 3's are part of (2, 3) and (3, 4) which should definitely not be the same point.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the cout line, and see what i and j is, when min becomes 0.
This should give you a clue. Maybe the error is in the dist-function.
It is definitly 'dist' that returns the 0. You have to find out when and why.

Answer (score 0):

[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin) was correct, it was because of the float data types I was using where I shouldn't be using them.